# Extracting information from string using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a text file with lines of the following format:

```
9999.0      @str:Attribute|ID=foo_1|SendingTime=2015-07-24 05:12:12.123|S-Id=9999|IDSource=Test_3|Qty=1555
```

From this I would like to get a hold of individual parts from each line, using a shell script. Say for example:

```
VAR1 = Attribute,
VAR2 = Date,
VAR3 = timeStamp,
VAR4 = Qty
```

The main problem is that the information comes in different orders and some with more/less unwanted data in each line. So splitting in to an array just wont cut it.

Comment: There's no `Date` nor `timeStamp` in the input. If you want to get concrete solutions, please use better sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I think the date and timestamp are extracted from the `SendingTime` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Example with `grep` with `Perl` regex:

```
#!/bin/bash
s="9999.0      @str:Attribute|ID=foo_1|SendingTime=2015-07-24 05:12:12.123|S-Id=9999|IDSource=Test_3|Qty=1555"
var1="$(echo "$s" |grep -oP "(?<=@str:)[^|]*")"        # @str:
var2="$(echo "$s" |grep -oP "(?<=SendingTime=)[^|]*")" # SendingTime=
var3="${var2#* }"                                      # Date
var2="${var2% *}"                                      # timestamp
var4="$(echo "$s" |grep -oP "(?<=Qty=)[^|]*")"         # Qty
echo "$var1 | $var2 | $var3 | $var4"
```

Output:

```
Attribute | 2015-07-24 | 05:12:12.123 | 1555
```

Comment: A lot of great help! A version of this is what i ended up using, thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

A general approach to parse complex lines is to use regular expressions to describe them and then use parentheses to notate which parts are interesting:

```
s='9999.0      @str:Attribute|ID=foo_1|SendingTime=2015-07-24 05:12:12.123|S-Id=9999|IDSource=Test_3|Qty=1555'
pattern='.*@str:\([^|]*\).*ID=\([^|]*\).*SendingTime=\([^|]*\).*Qty=\([^|]*\).*$'
extract_interesting() {
  input=$1
  pattern=$2
  echo "$input" | sed s/"$pattern"/'\1#\2#\3#\4'/
}
```

The function `extract_interesting()` will print the four interesting parts of the line, separated by `#` symbols:

```
extract_interesting "$s" "$pattern"
```

will print

```
Attribute#foo_1#2015-07-24 05:12:12.123#1555
```

To read this into separate shell variables, use this pattern:

```
IFS=# read a b c d < <(extract_interesting "$s" "$pattern")
```

Then

```
echo "$a"; echo "$b"; echo "$c"; echo "$d"
```

will print

```
Attribute
foo_1
2015-07-24 05:12:12.123
1555
```

Comment: I'd replace the all to `sed` with a `bash` regular expression match. `[[ $input =~ $pattern ]]`, then extract the 4 values from `BASH_REMATCH`.

Comment: You are right.  Same approach, different means.  I'm a little old-fashioned using `sed` here.

Comment: Forking a new process on each line is a lot of overhead.

Comment: Op says the information may come in different orders i.e `SendingTime=2015-07-24 05:12:12.123|S-Id=9999|...@str:Attribute|...` may be a valid line.

Comment: The approach then is still the same.  You just have to process each line more than once, maybe once for each interesting value.  Grab from the line each interesting information one at a time using the technique described above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Awk script which picks out the fields and prints them in the specified order.

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { f = split("Attribute|Date|timeStamp|Qty", k, /\|/) }
    { n = split($2, a, /\|/); for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
        if (a[i] ~ /^@str:/) v["Attribute"] = substr(a[i], 6);
        else if (a[i] ~ /^SendingTime=/) {
            v["Date"] = substr(a[i], 13, 10); v["timeStamp"] = substr(a[i], 24)
        } else if (a[i] ~ /^Qty=/) v["Qty"] = substr(a[i], 5);
    }
    for (s=1; s<=f; s++) printf("%s=%s\n", k[s], v[k[s]]);
    delete v }' inputfile
```

The `BEGIN` block sets up an array `k` of the labels of the fields we want to collect and print, in the order we want them.  The final `for` loop iterates over this array.  The main complexity is in the middle block where we further split the second field on the `|` separator and loop over the result; each field we want to extract is populated based on its offset in the match.

There is no check against a field being absent, and a number of assumptions about the input (tab-delimited, yes?) and output format because your question isn't very clear.

Online demo: http://ideone.com/2yvz2X